# Table Does Not Exist Error When Using write_pandas

Tags: pandas, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a very frustrating issue. At the bottom of this post is a function I created to (1) create a table in snowflake and (2) store a dataframe to that table.

The creation of the table is work fine. The issue is happening specifically with writepandas the code snippet:

```
    write_pandas(
                conn=conn,
                df=df,
                table_name=table_name,
                database=database,
                schema=schema
            )
```

I keep getting an error that the table I created "doesn't exist" because the naming convention is off .. for instance in the database the table is created as `"DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"` but the error message says `'DATABASE.SCHEMA."TABLE"' does not exist`

I know this is a simple issue but Im stuck for the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize 
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Text, String, DateTime
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from flatten_json import flatten
from snowflake.connector import connect
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
import os
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def create_store_snowflake(df,table):
    #quick transforms 
    df = df.rename(columns=str.upper)

    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('[-,/]','')
    #Define the table name, schema, and database you want to write to
    #Note: the table, schema, and database need to already exist in Snowflake
    
    #Define the table name, schema, and database you want to write to

    table_name = table
    schema = 'schema'
    database = 'database'

    #Connect to Snowflake using the required user

    conn = connect(
            user="user",
            password="password",
            account="account",
            role="role",
            database = "database",
            schema = 'schema'
        )

    #reroute raw data to dataframe variable
    dataframe = df

    #Create the SQL statement to create or replace the table

    create_tbl_statement = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE " + database + "." + schema + "." + table_name + " (\n"

    # Loop through each column finding the datatype and adding it to the statement

    for column in dataframe.columns:
        if (
        dataframe[column].dtype.name == "int"
        or dataframe[column].dtype.name == "int64"
        ):
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " int"
        elif dataframe[column].dtype.name == "object":
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " varchar(16777216)"
        elif dataframe[column].dtype.name == "datetime64[ns]":
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " datetime"
        elif dataframe[column].dtype.name == "float64":
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " float8"
        elif dataframe[column].dtype.name == "bool":
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " boolean"
        else:
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + column + " varchar(16777216)"

        # If column is not last column, add comma, else end sql-query
        if dataframe[column].name != dataframe.columns[-1]:
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + ",\n"
        else:
            create_tbl_statement = create_tbl_statement + ")"

    #Execute the SQL statement to create the table

    conn.cursor().execute(create_tbl_statement)

    print(f"{table_name} created!")

    #write df to created table
    write_pandas(
                conn=conn,
                df=df,
                table_name=table_name,
                database=database,
                schema=schema
            )

    print(df.shape[0],f"rows written to {table_name} in Snowflake")
```

Comment: Can you connect to snowflake and run show tables and see what you get in columns database and schema against the table you have created ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just had to make sure the tablename was CAPITALIZED as everything stored to Snowflake is apparently capitalized ::face-palm:: instead of `create_store_snowflake(df,'mynewtable')` it has to be `create_store_snowflake(df,'MYNEWTABLE')`

Comment: shoot, you saved me an hour. also make sure to change your df columns to be capitalized and without space. <p> data_df.columns = map(lambda x: str(x).upper().replace(' ', '_'), data_df.columns)

Answer (score 2):

When the table identifier is wrapped with  `"` during creation the followin rules applies:

```
create_tbl_statement= "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE " + database + "." + schema + "." + table_name
```

[Double-quoted Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#double-quoted-identifiers):

> **Delimited identifiers (i.e. identifiers enclosed in double quotes) are case-sensitive** and can start with and contain any valid characters
>
> ### Important
>
> If an object is created using a double-quoted identifier, when referenced in a query or any other SQL statement, **the identifier must be specified exactly as created, including the double quotes.** Failure to include the quotes might result in an **Object does not exist error (or similar type of error).**